# ASP.Net Web AP 2I: Should my models reflect tables from my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm creating an ASP.Net Web API 2 project that makes queries to an existing SQL Server database.

I'm currently creating seperate class models based on the shape of data I want to return to a user when a resource is hit.

For example:  Let's say I have a table in SQL Server that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t_movies (
  movieId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  openingDate DATE NOT NULL,
  category VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);
```

And I have a resource where all I want to retrieve is the movie's opening date and it's name.  I don't want to send the user the movieId or category along with the other data in this resource.  So I create a class inside the Model folder that looks like this:

```
public class MovieOpeningDate
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public DateTime openingDate { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to design a class that reflects the DB table like so:

```
public class Movie
{
  public int movieId { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public DateTime openingDate { get; set; }
  public string category { get; set; } 
}
```

and shape the data (remove class variables) before returning it inside my function?  I feel like the approach I'm currently taking is excessive and unnecessary.

Comment: It would! However, I have multiple resources that would use the same class, and I would want to return different variations of the Movie structure to them such as one that would return all columns in the query, one that would only return the category column, etc.  Sorry if this seems like an obvious question, I'm a bit of a noob to ASP.net and C# in general.

Comment: Assuming you are using an MVC design, this would appear to be a "viewmodel". A view model is the extra layer not mentioned when they describe how simple MVC (Model View Controller) is. Another option is simply use the same class and only display what you want to the end user.

Comment: How could I hide class variables I don't want the end user to see when I invoke a new instance of the class?

Comment: It is a good practice to use both models (which reflect your table) and view models which are specific to a particular view.  Since this is an api you don't have a view per say but you do have the specific information which will be delivered in the response which is the same basic idea.